# How to read newpost return post ID value as integer for xmlrpc

Tags: xml-rpc

I would like to read the $remote_id as integer, $remote_id should be post_id after executing metaweblog.newpost. Does anyone know how to transform the data as integer?

Here are the codes below:

```
$MAINURL = "http://mywordpress.com";
$USERNAME = "username";
$PASSWORD = "password";

function get_response($URL, $context) {
if(!function_exists('curl_init')) {
die ("Curl PHP package not installed\n");
}

/*Initializing CURL*/
$curlHandle = curl_init();

/*The URL to be downloaded is set*/
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $context);

/*Now execute the CURL, download the URL specified*/
$response = curl_exec($curlHandle);
return $response;
}

/*Creating the metaWeblog.newPost request which takes on five parameters
blogid,
username,
password*/

/*The title of your post*/
$title = "Sample Post from main site";

/*The contents of your post*/
$description = "This is a sample post from main site";

/*Forming the content of blog post*/
$content['title'] = $title;
$content['description'] = $description;
$content['categories'] = array("mycategoryname");
$content['post_status'] = 'publish';  /* 'publish' or 'draft' or 'pending'
/*Whether the post has to be published*/
$toPublish = true;


$request = xmlrpc_encode_request("metaWeblog.newPost", 
array(1,$USERNAME, $PASSWORD, $content, $toPublish));

/*Making the request to wordpress XMLRPC of your blog*/
$xmlresponse = get_response($MAINURL."/xmlrpc.php", $request);
$remote_id = xmlrpc_decode($xmlresponse);

echo $remote_id;

$MAINURL = "http://mywordpress.com";
$USERNAME = "username";
$PASSWORD = "password";

function get_response($URL, $context) {
if(!function_exists('curl_init')) {
die ("Curl PHP package not installed\n");
}

/*Initializing CURL*/
$curlHandle = curl_init();

/*The URL to be downloaded is set*/
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $context);

/*Now execute the CURL, download the URL specified*/
$response = curl_exec($curlHandle);
return $response;
}

/*Creating the metaWeblog.newPost request which takes on five parameters
blogid,
username,
password*/

/*The title of your post*/
$title = "Sample Post from main site";

/*The contents of your post*/
$description = "This is a sample post from main site";

/*Forming the content of blog post*/
$content['title'] = $title;
$content['description'] = $description;
$content['categories'] = array("mycategoryname");
$content['post_status'] = 'publish';  /* 'publish' or 'draft' or 'pending'
/*Whether the post has to be published*/
$toPublish = true;


$request = xmlrpc_encode_request("metaWeblog.newPost", 
array(1,$USERNAME, $PASSWORD, $content, $toPublish));

/*Making the request to wordpress XMLRPC of your blog*/
$xmlresponse = get_response($MAINURL."/xmlrpc.php", $request);
$remote_id = xmlrpc_decode($xmlresponse);

echo $remote_id;
```

Comment: Provide the output of `var_dump( $remote_id );` and state why you need it as an integer.

Answer (score -1):

use it like this:

`$post_id = (int) $remote_id;`

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?